# Windows Server licensing when exporting VM from Google Cloud

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, licensing

I have a WS 2012 R2 VM running under Google Cloud Platform. It is using a datacenter WS license provided by Google. What are the options to export that VM to an on-premises infrastructure and keep WS running? Do I need a datacenter license or can I re-activate (if exporting is possible under such scenario) using WS 2012 R2 Standard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to exporting the VM instance to VMware vCenter (on-premise) based on that the option is, create an image from the [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image) then create [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) to [export](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image_with_a_single_command) the image to the bucket as a disk.raw file and compress it into a tar.gz file format then [download](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#create-export-manually) the tar.gz file.

For for activating the license please follow the [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/bring-your-own-license/frequently-asked-questions#how_do_i_activate_my_byol_licenses).